# Getting Started with the Light Dom

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to learn the LWC Light Dom feature and need help to get a hello world up and running.

Here is my HTML file for my top-level component. Nothing special just one child component that uses light dom.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>My Light Dom App</h1>
        <c-light-header></c-light-header>
    </div>
</template>
```

Then I have JS file. I expect to see the child header show in the console. But it reads as null.

```
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';

export default class MyLightDomApp extends LightningElement {

  renderedCallback() {
     console.log(` my light dom header ${this.getElementsByClassName('light-header')}`)
  }

}
```

Then I have a file that is declared as myLightDomApp.scoped.css. The values of the container class are not being applied to the top level div with the class container. And the p element in the child is not being rendered in red.

```
p {
    color: red;
}

.container {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

Here is the child html file

```
<template lwc:render-mode="light">
    <h1 class='light-header'>Light Header</h1>
    <p class='light-header-text'>I am the light header content</p>
</template>
```

And the child JS file.

```
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';

export default class LightHeader extends LightningElement {
    static renderMode = 'light';

}
```

What am I missing here about selecting elements from child components using the light dom and styling children?

Comment: I tried the above code and i'am able to see the child header in console. Also , `scoped` css is used for encapsulating css to specific component (same as shadow dom).

Comment: I  could see the header. But I shouldn't I be able to also select the header in my parent component in my rendered callback hook?

Comment: Yes , I tried the same code and I was able to see the child header in console.

Comment: hmm wonder if it is something with scratch orgs.

Comment: What do you see in the browser console Elements section?